# I want to show the UILabel text "sunday" to uppercase "SUN" like that

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uilabel

```
NSString *strDay = [dic objectForKey:@"day"]; 
NSString *uppercaseString = [strDay uppercaseString];
cell.dayLabel.text = uppercaseString;
```

Is that the correct method to get that? But I get only uppercase. I want "sunday" to be shown in view like "SUN".

Comment: From where did you get `dic`?

Comment: you can just print the first three letters only (after uppercasing)

Comment: does this need to work with non-English locales?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

How about just this

```
NSString *uppercaseString = [strDay uppercaseString];
cell.dayLabel.text = [uppercaseString substringToIndex:3];
```

Assuming it has a valid day

Comment: +1. If this only needs to work with English, then this is what I would do. If you need other locales, I'd look up the docs about date formats.

Comment: Thanks man...If i want TODAY to be shown completely then what should i do

Comment: Than change the last line with this..  cell.dayLabel.text = [uppercaseString isEqualToString:@"TODAY"] ? uppercaseString : [uppercaseString substringToIndex:3];

Comment: i used ur code. but can u write the code here.. so that i can understand completely

Comment: `NSString *strDay = [dic objectForKey:@"day"];
    NSString *uppercaseString = [strDay uppercaseString];
    cell.dayLabel.text = [uppercaseString isEqualToString:@"TODAY"] ? uppercaseString : [uppercaseString substringToIndex:3];`

Answer (score 3):

```
NSString *strDay = [dic objectForKey:@"day"]; 
NSString* split = [strDay substringToIndex:3];
split=[split uppercaseString];
```

NSLOG (@"%@",split);

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *strDay = @"sunday";
NSString *newStr = [strDay substringToIndex:3];
NSString *uppercaseString = [newStr uppercaseString];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *strDay = [dic objectForKey:@"day"]; 
cell.dayLabel.text = [strDay.uppercaseString substringToIndex:3]
```